# Prove a von Neumann algebra is diffuse

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

In Lemma 2.2, The authors want to prove $M_{\varphi}$ is diffuse. How to check that $eMe$ falls in $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't this it's automatically obvious that "$eMe\subset A$". But it is of course true, and it follows easily from an attempt to see that if $e$ is minimal in $A$ then it is minimal in $M$.

Indeed, let $f\in eMe$ be a projection.  For any $a\in A$, and using that $Ae=\mathbb C\,e$,
$$
fa=fea=f\lambda_ae=\lambda_aef=aef=af.
$$
So $f\in A'=A$. Then $f\in Ae=\mathbb Ce$. Thus $eMe=\mathbb C\,e$.

Comment: Your displayed equation shows $eMe\subset A'=A$, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. What I tried to convey is that when I saw the assertion that $eMe\subset A$, I didn't see it. In trying to show that $e$ is minimal, the computation you mention comes naturally.